# offloading to ffmpeg via named pipes in c#/dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffmpeg, named-pipes

I tried to break this down to the base elements so I hope this is clear. I want to take in a network stream, it may be a 1 way,  it may be a protocol that requires 2 way communication, such as RTMP during handshake.

I want to pass that stream straight through to a spawned FFMPEG process. I then want to capture the output of FFMPEG, in this example I just want to pipe it out to a file. The file is not my end goal, but for simplicity if I can get that far I think I'll be ok.

[image]

I want the code to be as plain as possible and offload the core processing to FFMPEG. If I ask FFMPEG to output webrtc stream, a file, whatever, I just want to capture that. FFMPEG shouldn't be used directly, just indirectly via `IncomingConnectionHandler`.

Only other component is OBS, which I am using to create the RTMP stream coming in.

As things stand now, running this results in the following error, which I'm a little unclear on. I don't feel like I'm causing concurrent reads at any point.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Concurrent reads are not allowed
         at Medallion.Shell.Throw`1.If(Boolean condition, String message)
         at Medallion.Shell.Streams.Pipe.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Medallion.Shell.Streams.Pipe.PipeOutputStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLineAsyncInternal()
         at Medallion.Shell.Streams.MergedLinesEnumerable.GetEnumeratorInternal()+MoveNext()
         at System.String.Join(String separator, IEnumerable`1 values)
         at VideoIngest.IncomingRtmpConnectionHandler.OnConnectedAsync(ConnectionContext connection) in Program.cs:line 55
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelConnection`1.ExecuteAsync()
```

Code:

```
namespace VideoIngest
{
    public class IncomingRtmpConnectionHandler : ConnectionHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IncomingRtmpConnectionHandler> logger;

        public IncomingRtmpConnectionHandler(ILogger<IncomingRtmpConnectionHandler> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync(ConnectionContext connection)
        {
            logger?.LogInformation("connection started");

            var outputFileName = @"C:\Temp\bunny.mp4";

            var rtmpPassthroughPipeName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var cmdPath = @"C:\Opt\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
            var cmdArgs = $"-i pipe:{rtmpPassthroughPipeName} -preset slow -c copy -f mp4 -y pipe:1";

            var cancellationToken = connection.ConnectionClosed;
            var rtmpStream = connection.Transport;

            using (var outputStream = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create))
            using (var cmd = Command.Run(cmdPath, options: o => { o.StartInfo(i => i.Arguments = cmdArgs); o.CancellationToken(cancellationToken); }))
            {
                // create a pipe to pass the RTMP data straight to FFMPEG. This code should be dumb to proto etc being used
                var ffmpegPassthroughStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(rtmpPassthroughPipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 10, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

                // take the network stream and pass data to/from ffmpeg process
                var fromFfmpegTask = ffmpegPassthroughStream.CopyToAsync(rtmpStream.Output.AsStream(), cancellationToken);
                var toFfmpegTask = rtmpStream.Input.AsStream().CopyToAsync(ffmpegPassthroughStream, cancellationToken);

                // take the ffmpeg process output (not stdout) into target file
                var outputTask = cmd.StandardOutput.PipeToAsync(outputStream);

                while (!outputTask.IsCompleted && !outputTask.IsCanceled)
                {
                    var errs = cmd.GetOutputAndErrorLines();
                    logger.LogInformation(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errs));

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }

                CommandResult result = result = cmd.Result;

                if (result != null && result.Success)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("Created file");
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.LogError(result.StandardError);
                }
            }

            logger?.LogInformation("connection closed");
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var log = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Startup>>();
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddLogging(options =>
                    {
                        options.AddDebug().AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                    });
                })
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(15666, builder =>
                    {
                        builder.UseConnectionHandler<IncomingRtmpConnectionHandler>();
                    });

                    options.ListenLocalhost(5000);

                    // HTTPS 5001
                    options.ListenLocalhost(5001, builder =>
                    {
                        builder.UseHttps();
                    });
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
    

}
```

Questions:

1. Is this a valid approach, do you see any fundamental issues?
2. Is the pipe naming correct, is the convention just `pipe:someName`?
3. Any ideas on what specifically may be causing the `Concurrent reads are not allowed`?
4. If #3 is solved, does the rest of this seem valid?

Comment: For starter `while (!outputTask.IsCompleted && !outputTask.IsCanceled)` you are killing CPU. Why not `await`, after all from your code it is apparent you are aware of it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the problem is that a named pipe on Windows is not the same as on linux. FFMpeg works with fifo (see mkfifo command), which also is called 'named pipe'. The files are not servers and the NamedPipeServer is meant for using on a server process on Windows (they are sockets).
2. If you insist using pipe:name remove the 'pipe:' part.

I got it working using this.Here we use the StdOut to pass the ffmpeg output and pass it to asp.net. Note that this command consumes quite some CPU. This is because it cannot just 'pass' the codec from the rtsp stream as is.

```
   using var ffMpegProc = Command.Run("ffmpeg",arguments: new object []{ 
                "-re", 
                "-rtsp_transport", "tcp", 
                "-max_delay", "30000000",
                "-i", rtspStream,
                 "-g", "52",
                 "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov", 
                "-c:v", "h264",
                "-an",   
                "-f",  "mp4",               
                "-y", "-"},
                 options:  o => o.CancellationToken(cancellation));

    try
    {
        var proc = ffMpegProc.RedirectStandardErrorTo(Console.Error)
            > output;
        await proc.Task;
    


    }
    catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
      
        //nothing 
        _logger.LogError($"RtspToMp4 {ex.Message}");
    }
```